# Number of qubits in quantum circuits in ibm qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, experimental-realization, bb84

How to find number of Qubits ?

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister

bob   = QuantumRegister(8,'b')
alice = ClassicalRegister(2,'a')
eve   = QuantumRegister(4,'e')
qc = QuantumCircuit(bob, alice, eve)
```

I know of syntax
`QuantumCircuit(2, 2)` ie. 2 parameter but not sure about 3 parameter.

Comment: It's IBM qiskit  and language is python

Comment: Is your question how to extract the number of qubits from an instance of `QuantumCircuit`? Theres a `QuantumCircuit.num_qubits` attribute for this.

Comment: Yeah. But how to extract without using QuantumCircuit.num_qubits attribute ?

Comment: So in your code why can't you just do `print(qc.num_qubits)` to get the number of  qubits?

Comment: Because I wanted to understand the code behavior and how it works in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: With [`QuantumCircuit.num_qubits`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.num_qubits):

```
>>> print(qc.num_qubits)
12
```

A list of them, via [`QuantumCircuit.qubits`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.qubits):

```
>>> print(qc.qubits)
[Qubit(QuantumRegister(8, 'b'), 0),
 Qubit(QuantumRegister(8, 'b'), 1),
 Qubit(QuantumRegister(8, 'b'), 2),
 Qubit(QuantumRegister(8, 'b'), 3),
 Qubit(QuantumRegister(8, 'b'), 4),
 Qubit(QuantumRegister(8, 'b'), 5),
 Qubit(QuantumRegister(8, 'b'), 6),
 Qubit(QuantumRegister(8, 'b'), 7),
 Qubit(QuantumRegister(4, 'e'), 0),
 Qubit(QuantumRegister(4, 'e'), 1),
 Qubit(QuantumRegister(4, 'e'), 2),
 Qubit(QuantumRegister(4, 'e'), 3)]
```

---

The QuantumCircuit constructor documentation can be found [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html):

> **`regs`** (list(`Register`) or list(`int`) or list(list(`Bit`))) – The registers to be included in the circuit.

This means, that the registers `bob`, `alice`, and `eve` are included. Their length is 8, 2, and 4 respectably. However, `alice` is a classical register, which does not extend the amount of qubit. So, $8+4=12$.